# Iterate over a string with #split method, how to get the total number of elements

Tags: ruby, split, loops

I have the following code

```
s = 'string1, string2, string3, string4'

s.split(",").each_with_index{ |element, index| puts "line #{index} of #{size_of_array}" }
```

What is the best way to get the size of the array ? Is there a method that I can call on the same line of the split passing to the loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for tap:

```
s.split(',').tap{|a| a.size.times{|i| puts "line #{i} of #{a.size}"}}
```

but really, just a ; keeps as much as you want on the same line:

```
a = s.split(','); a.size.times{|i| puts "line #{i} of #{a.size}"}
```

Notice size instead of length because it's 2 chars shorter.

Answer (score 1):

To get the size of the array you simple call `.length` on it. Now, I don't think you can do this on the same line, would the following work for you:?

```
s = 'string1, string2, string3, string4'
split_s = s.split()
split_s.each_with_index{ |element, index| puts "line #{index} of #{split_s.length}"}
```

If this is not acceptable let me know, and I'll see if there's something else that can be done.

**UPDATE**

If you want it all in one line, there will be a lot of redundancy. For example, you could do:

```
s = 'string1, string2, string3, string4'

s.split(",").each_with_index{ |element, index| puts "line #{index} of #{s.split(',').length}" }
```

But do you see the redundancy? s.split(',') is called for every element. That's why I suggested storing it in a different line as above.

**UPDATE 2**

As per the below comment, it would also be efficient to store `split_s.length` before calling the `each_with_index` loop as it will also loop through the elements. Thank you commenter! I had previously assumed that the `length` property was set upon generation and updated upon the removal and addition of objects to an array.

Comment: FYI, that `split_s.length` call is going to iterate over the array each time, so this is an O(n^2) loop, so you should cache that too :).

Comment: @mjpy3: Yeah, I used to assume that too :(. It was a sad day when I checked the source code of [Array#length](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-length). At least the C source is pretty easy to read, even without a pointers-for-breakfast C background.

Comment: Yeah I knew about the .length. I wanted to know if there was something like .foreach_with_index_length.  But I guess not. Thanks for the help really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a faster way of doing it:

```
s = 'string1, string2, string3, string4'
(length = s.count(',')) && (length + 1).times{|i| puts "line #{i} of #{length}" }
```

Comment: Please provide evidence of "faster" in the future. I [benchmarked it](https://gist.github.com/3671729) for you though, and yes, it is faster (~2.7 s on a 10M element array). However, it's marginally faster on smaller strings, and more importantly, it's much less readable.